# MVC - Model validation does not fire when using EditorTemplate with EditorForModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates, html.beginform

I'm using `EditorTemplate` for `Html.EditorForModel()`
When used without `EditorTemplate`, validation works.
Without `EditorTemplate` - validation does not work.

This is my Form:

```
<div style="padding-top: 20px;">
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
        @Html.EditorForModel()
   }
</div>
```

This is EditorTemplate:

```
<div style="margin: 0px auto; text-align: center; display: table;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "username" } })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "password" } })</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:70px;">
            <td><input type="submit" class="k-primary" value="Log In" /></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

This is `html` generated:[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, is there a reason you're using an EditorForModel with an EditorTemplate, as opposed to inserting the contents of the EditorTemplate directly in the form?

Comment: No reasons. Just for self-educational purpose :)

Comment: OK, fair enough!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding `Html.ValidationMessageFor` for both properties

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserName,"", new { @class = "text-danger"})`